# returns the smallest positive integer (greater than 0) that does not occur in Array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the following question:-

Write a function:

```
class Solution { public int solution(int[] A); }
```

that, given an array A of N integers, returns the smallest positive integer (greater than 0) that does not occur in A.

For example, given A = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2], the function should return 5.

Given A = [1, 2, 3], the function should return 4.

Given A = [−1, −3], the function should return 1.

Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:

- N is an integer within the range [1..100,000];
- each element of array A is an integer within the range [−1,000,000..1,000,000].

now i tried this code:-

```
using System;
// you can also use other imports, for example:
// using System.Collections.Generic;

// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// Console.WriteLine("this is a debug message");

class Solution
{
    public int solution(int[] A)
    {
        // write your code in C# 6.0 with .NET 4.5 (Mono)
        int n = 1;
        Array.Sort(A);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100000; i++)
        {
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 <= A.Length - 1; i2++)
            {
                if (A[i2] == i)

                {
                    n = A[i2] + 1;
                    break;
                }

            }



        }
        return n;

    }
}
```

where my code worked well for these test data:-

A = [1, 2, 3]

A = [−1, −3]

while failed for this one:-

A = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2] where it return 7 instead of 5.

any advice why my code failed on the 3rd test?

Thanks

Comment: @TimSchmelter so any advice on how i can fix this?

Comment: Wouldn't a better approach be to (1) Sort as you already do, (2) Binary chop to find the value 1 or the nearest place where the 1 would go. (3) Linear search from that index onwards to find the first "gap" (handling the case where 1 is missing and is therefore the answer)

Comment: @MatthewWatson can you provide a sample code

Comment: I just think that would be better, but the constraints on N lead me to conclude that there is an even better cleverer algorithm. This bears thinking about some more.

Comment: The inner (`i2`) loop detects if `i` is part of the `A` array. Once found, it breaks and the next `i` is taken. The problem here is that the outer loop always runs to completion, so at some point `i` is 6, and the inner loop finds a match, overwriting the correct value for `n`. You might want to check the _current_ value of `n` before you assign a new value to it, see if there's a gap? (note I'm not discussing efficiency here)

Comment: I cheated and looked this up, and there are two generally accepted answers - one of which is basically Tim's answer below. The other involves some clever stuff to do with using a pivot (from a Quicksort algorithm) and some interesting logic to find the lowest number after that - but I suspect that's out of scope for any answers here.

Comment: What is efficient? [Memory-efficient](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NFy3AB)?

Comment: Your mistake is that you have to variables, `i` and `n`, that basically mean the same: The current integer to look for. Why are they even separate variables?
You look for `i`, but if you find it, you increment `n` and then keep looking for `i`

Comment: If you can sort the array in-place and don't want to allocate additional memory you can sort it, and then just start from the start. The sequence of values should "negative values, 1, 2, 3, etc.". Just skip the negative values, if any, and then the next value should be 1, then it should be 2, etc. If you miss a value, this is the result. If you don't miss a value, the result is last value + 1. This is basically a sort + a linear walk of the array. You will likely also have to handle duplicates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;

int smallestNumber = Enumerable.Range(1, 100000).Except(A).Min();
```

Comment: Note that this approach does create a set containing 100K elements - which may violate the "efficient" requirement of the OP. Clearly the OP has marked this as the answer, but we might have to wait to see whether it passes the teacher's assignment ;)

Comment: Enumerable.Range(1, A.Length + 1) should be enough I guess..

Comment: I did a benchmark running this 100,000 times, and compared to simply looping 0-1,000,000 and checking if it's in A or not, this solution used an average of 72.31 seconds compared to an average of 0,28 seconds, both in 8 runs with the same random A-content. So, about 255 times slower than simply loop-checking the array with IndexOf :-/ This solution is by far a prettier and simpler code, but slooooow in comparison to manually looping the array (which isn't optimal either).

Answer (score 4):

I would use following approach that uses a `HashSet<int>` to check if a given integer is missing:

```
public static int? SmallestMissing(int[] A, int rangeStart = 1, int rangeEnd = 100_000)
{
     HashSet<int> hs = new HashSet<int>(A);
     for (int i = rangeStart; i <= rangeEnd; i++)
        if(!hs.Contains(i)) return i;
     
     return null;
}
```

A [`HashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-5.0) is a collection if unique values and it's very efficient in lookup items(complexity is `O(1)`). So you get a very readable and efficient algorithm at the cost of some memory.

Maybe you could optimize it by providing another algorithm in case the array is very large, you don't want to risk an `OutOfMemoryException`:

```
public static int? SmallestMissing(int[] A, int rangeStart = 1, int rangeEnd = 100_000)
{
    if(A.Length > 1_000_000)
    {
        Array.Sort(A);
        for (int i = rangeStart; i <= rangeEnd; i++)
        {
            int index = Array.BinarySearch(A, i);
            if(index < 0) return i;
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    HashSet<int> hs = new HashSet<int>(A);
    for (int i = rangeStart; i <= rangeEnd; i++)
        if(!hs.Contains(i)) return i;
 
    return null;
}
```

Comment: but should it retunr i+1 ? and not i ?

Comment: @JohnJohn: No, OP wants to "return the smallest positive integer  that does not occur in an Array". I guess that misunderstanding comes from OP's approach to order that large array first and iterate it in a nested loop.

Comment: @TimSchmelter he _is_ the OP

Comment: @C.Evenhuis: fair point :D No you don't need to return the number+1 because you iterate all possible numbers and simply check if they are contained in the set. No need to ordering the whole array and to loop it always.

Answer (score 3):

If you're allowed to sort the array in-place, which means modifying the input parameter value, here's a simple linear probe for the missing value (on top of the sort of course).

Here's the pseudo-code:

```
Sort the array
Skip all negatives and 0's at the start
Loopify the following:
    Expect 1, if not found at current location return 1
    Skip all 1's
    Expect 2, if not found at current location return 2
    Skip all 2's
    Expect 3, if not found at current location return 3
    Skip all 3's
    ... and so on for 4, 5, 6, etc. until end of array
If we get here, return currently expected value which should've been at the end
```

Here's the code:

```
public static int FirstMissingValue(int[] input)
{
    Array.Sort(input);
    
    int index = 0;
    
    // Skip negatives
    while (index < input.Length && input[index] < 1)
        index++;

    int expected = 1;
    while (index < input.Length)
    {
        if (input[index] > expected)
            return expected;
            
        // Skip number and all duplicates
        while (index < input.Length && input[index] == expected)
            index++;
            
        expected++;
    }
    
    return expected;
}
```

Test-cases:

```
Console.WriteLine(FirstMissingValue(new[] { 1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2 }));
Console.WriteLine(FirstMissingValue(new[] { 1, 2, 3 }));
Console.WriteLine(FirstMissingValue(new[] { -1, -3 }));
```

output:

```
5
4
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your alg won't work in case input array becomes like this: [1,2-1,1,3,5]. I did this based on your alg. Give it a try:

```
int[] a = new int[] { -1, -2};

        IEnumerable<int> uniqueItems = a.Distinct<int>().Where(x => x > 0);
        
        if (uniqueItems.Count() == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("result: 1");
        }
        else
        {
            Array asList = uniqueItems.ToArray();
            Array.Sort(asList);

            for (int i = 1; i <= 100000; i++)
            {
                if ((int)asList.GetValue(i - 1) != i)

                {
                    Console.WriteLine("result: " + i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is C#, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this.

```
    public static int solution(int[] A)
    {
        int smallest = -1;
        Array.Sort(A);
        if(A[0] > 1)
            return 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
        {
          
            if(A.Length != i+1 && A[i] + 1 != A[i + 1] && A[i+1] > 0)
            {
                smallest = A[i]+1;
                break;
            }
            else if(A[i] > 0 && A.Length == i+1)
            {
                smallest = A[i] + 1;
            }
        }
        return smallest > 0 ? smallest:1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the approach that uses `O(N)` partitioning followed by an `O(N)` search. This approach does not use any additional storage, but it DOES change the contents of the array.

This code was converted [from here](https://www.techiedelight.com/find-smallest-missing-positive-number-unsorted-array). Also see [this article](https://www.techiedelight.com/find-smallest-missing-positive-number-unsorted-array).

I've added comments to try to explain how the second stage `findSmallestMissing()` works. I've not commented the partitioning method, since that's just a variant of a standard partition as might be used in a QuickSort algorithm.

```
static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(FindSmallestMissing(1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2));
        Console.WriteLine(FindSmallestMissing(1, 2, 3));
        Console.WriteLine(FindSmallestMissing(-1, -3));
    }

    public static int FindSmallestMissing(params int[] array)
    {
        return findSmallestMissing(array, partition(array));
    }

    // Places all the values > 0 before any values <= 0,
    // and returns the index of the first value <= 0.
    // The values are unordered.

    static int partition(int[] arr)
    {
        void swap(int x, int y)
        {
            var temp = arr[x];
            arr[x]   = arr[y];
            arr[y]   = temp;
        }

        int pIndex = 0; // Index of pivot.

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] > 0) // pivot is 0, hence "> 0"
                swap(i, pIndex++);
        }

        return pIndex;
    }

    // This is the clever bit.
    // We will use the +ve values in the array as flags to indicate that the number equal to that index is
    // present in the array, by making the value negative if it is found in the array.
    // This way we can store both the original number AND whether or not the number equal to that index is present
    // in a single value.
    //
    // Given n numbers that are all > 0, find the smallest missing number as follows:
    //
    // For each array index i in (0..n):
    //     val = |arr[i]| - 1;          // Subtract 1 so val will be between 0 and max +ve value in original array.
    //     if (val is in range)         // If val beyond the end of the array we can ignore it
    //     and arr[val] is non-negative // If already negative, no need to make it negative.
    //        make arr[val] negative
    //
    // After that stage, we just need to find the first positive number in the array, which indicates that
    // the number equal to that index + 1 is missing.

    // n = number of values at the start of the array that are > 0
    static int findSmallestMissing(int[] arr, int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int val = Math.Abs(arr[i]) - 1;

            if (val < n && arr[val] >= 0)
                arr[val] = -arr[val];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] > 0)   // Missing number found.
                return i + 1;
        }

        return n + 1; // No missing number found.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int [] A = new int[]  {1, 2, 3};
        int n = 0;
        bool found = false;
        Array.Sort(A);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100000; i++) {
            for (int x = 0; x <= A.Length - 1; x++) {
                int next = (x + 1) < A.Length ? (x + 1): x;
                if (A[x] > 0 && (A[next] - A[x]) > 0) {
                    n = A[x] + 1;
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(found) {
                break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Smallest number: " + n);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation?

Answer (score 0):

```
 int smallestNumber=Enumerable.Range(1,(int.Parse(A.Length.ToString())+1)).Except(A).Min();
    Array.Sort(A);
    for (int number = 1; number <= 100000; number++)
    {
        for (int num = number; i2 <= A.Length - 1; num++)
        {
            if (A[num] == number)

            {
                smallestNumber = A[num] + 1;
                break;
            }

        }
    } 
    return smallestNumber; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest one :)

```
class Solution
{
    public int solution(int[] array)
    {
        int[] onlyPositiveArray = array.Where(a => a > 0).OrderBy(a => a).Distinct().ToArray();

        int smallestNumber = 1;
        foreach (var number in onlyPositiveArray)
        {
            if (smallestNumber  != number)
            {
                break;
            }

            smallestNumber ++;
        }

        if (!onlyPositiveArray.Contains(smallestNumber ))
        {
            return smallestNumber;
        }
        else
        {
            return smallestNumber  + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution, also if someone could test how performant it is?

```js
public int solution(int[] N) {
  if (N.Length == 0)
    return 1;
  else if (N.Length == 1)
    return N[0] >= 0 ? N[0] + 1 : 1;

  Array.Sort(N);
  int min = Array.Find(N, IsUnderZero);
  if (min ==
    default)
    return 1;
  HashSet < int > hashSet = new HashSet < int > (N);

  int max = N[N.Length - 1];
  for (int i = min + 1; i <= max + 1; i++) {
    if (!hashSet.Contains(i) && i > 0)
      return i;
  }

  return max + 1;

  bool IsUnderZero(int i) => i <= 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
 public static int MinIntegerGreaterThanZeroInArray(int[] A)
    {
        int minInt;
        if (A.Length > 0)
        {
            Array.Sort(A);
            for (minInt = 1; minInt <= A.Length; minInt++)
            {
                int index = Array.BinarySearch(A, minInt);
                if (index < 0) return minInt;
            }
            return minInt;
        }
        
        //Array is empty.
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static int Smallest(int[] A)
    {
        int maxPositiveInt = 1;
        HashSet<int> NumDic = new HashSet<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
        {
            if (A[i] <= 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (!NumDic.Contains(A[i]))
            { 
                NumDic.Add(A[i]); 
            }
            maxPositiveInt = Math.Max(A[i], maxPositiveInt);
        }

        //All numbers are negative
        if (NumDic.Count == 0) 
         {
           return 1;
         }

        int smallestinteger = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
        {
            if (A[i] <= 0) 
            { 
                continue; 
            }
            if (!NumDic.Contains(smallestinteger))
            {
                return smallestinteger;
            }

            else
            {
                smallestinteger++;
            }
        }

        return maxPositiveInt + 1;
    }
```

Comment: I came up with this to avoid sorting and improve performance.

Answer (score -1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(solution(new int[]{1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2}));
    }
    public static int solution(int[] A)
    {
        Array.Sort(A);
        int smallest = A[0];
        while (A.Contains(smallest+1)|| (smallest+1)<1)
        {
            smallest++;
        }
        return smallest +1;
        
    }
```

Comment: There are already other answers with votes, 6+ for the accepted answer, please add more details and explanation on how your answer address the OP's question.